# React.js unit testing with d3-npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am creating a forced graph in react using d3 for npm.
The graph is created using the follows:

https://medium.com/walmartlabs/d3v4-forcesimulation-with-react-8b1d84364721

I am trying to set up the testing environment as follows:
https://ericnish.io/blog/how-to-unit-test-react-components-with-enzyme/

the problem is when I run the test I keep on getting

```
 Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined
at C:\workspace\project\node_modules\d3-selection\build\d3-selection.js:83:15
```

I have imported d3 in my graph component as follows:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

It seems like when I import my react component in my test file, it freaks out. This is my test file:

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow, mount, render} from 'enzyme'
import {expect} from 'chai'
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import graph from '.../components/graph ';
describe('graph ', () => {
  it('should have the main svg', (done) => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<graph />);
    expect(wrapper.find('svg')).to.have.length(1);
    done()
  })
})
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file, e.g. *polyfill.js*:

```
global.document.documentElement = {matches: () => false};
```

And import it right before you import DS3 (or any other import that transitively imports D3):

```
import React from 'react'
import {shallow, mount, render} from 'enzyme'
import {expect} from 'chai'
import './polyfill';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```